# How do I get Visual Studio Code to show its icon on the taskbar in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons, visual-studio-code

Here's Visual Studio code in Windows explorer - note the icon

[image]

And here it is in the taskbar, when I right-clicked it.

[image]

It never has its own icon on the taskbar, even if I don't right click - I only did that to show the "new window" option has the correct icon.

How do I get the app to show its icon on the task bar?

Comment: Try and reinstall the application on the main system drive instead of a secondary drive.  Wasn’t able to reproduce this behavior when I installed the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following steps to change taskbar icon

1. Hold **SHIFT** and right-click on the taskbar item
2. Select **Properties**

[image]

3. In **Shortcut** tab, click **Change Icon** at the bottom

[image]

4. Click **Browse** to locate the Code.exe icon. Apply and OK

[image]

5. Restart Windows Explorer.exe in task manager

Comment: Althoguh I accpted your answer, it didn;t quite work at the start. "`¬Hold SHIFT and right-click on the taskbar item`" just brought the program to foreground. If I lcosed it, it woudl not be on the taskbar, so I pinned it & closed it - no use. Unpinned & went over the start menu; chose "show in folder", then properties, then your solution works - Thanks (answer and upvote) !

Comment: Maybe some apps cannot open the properities by thta way. Anyway, glad to know the issue is resolved.

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica if the shift+right click brings up the jump list, keep holding shift and right click again on the program itself in the jump list to get the rest of the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

Pinning and unpinning the program only fixed the problem temporarily for me.
Shift+Right-clicking the icon in the task bar, like @Seven suggests in an answer, brings up the same context menu as right-clicking

Here's what fixed the issue for me:

1. Right-click the program in the task bar without holding shift. The list of recently opened files should appear, along with "Visual Studio Code", "Pin to task bar" and "Close window" at the bottom.
2. Right-click "Visual Studio Code". (I thought holding shift was necessary here, but that's not the case.) A context menu should appear.
3. Click "Properties". The properties of a link file should appear. (Note: I don't have VS Code pinned to the task bar, so I don't even know why there's a link file here.) In my case, there were wrong paths in the "Target" and "Execute in" boxes.
4. Fix the paths and click OK. The correct icon should now be shown.

The screenshot is in german, but it should give you an idea of where to look:
[image]